# Logo and button not showing on the header on Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 and I'm facing some issues with the navigation menu on Safari starting from 8 and down.

The logo at the left is an image and two buttons('Login', 'Sign Up') at the right are not shown on Safari, I used a live testing website for simulating Safari 6 and I inspected the element and I see that they are in the Dom and taking space in the header, But none of them is shown.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6rc4d7g

Live preview:

```css
.btn-red{
  background: #d9534f;
  color: #fff !important
}
```

```html
<!-- Fontawesome 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- tether -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable fixed-top">
  <div class="container hidden-md-down">
    <div class="navbar-collapse clearfix">
      <a class="navbar-brand float-left" href="#">
        <img class="mt-1" src="http://placehold.it/1121x171/200" width="200" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <div class="text-center" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 5px; ">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link hiw-link" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link hiw-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="float-right ml-auto" style="margin-top: 5px; ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav float-right ">  
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-red nav-button" href="/new">Sign up</a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .navbar-collapse -->
  </div> <!-- .hidden-md-down -->
  <div class="hidden-lg-up">
    <a class="navbar-brand py-0 float-left mt-3" href="#">
      <img style="margin-top: 7px" src="http://placehold.it/1121x171/200" width="150" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <a class="btn mobile_header_button float-left btn-red mt-3" href="/new">Sign up</a> 
    <a class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler-right gray-light float-right" data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
      </a>
  </div> <!-- .hidden-lg-up -->
</nav> <!-- .navbar -->
```

What is causing this issue and how to solve it?!

Comment: Does this happen on later versions of safari? Safari 6 is quite old so It might not support bootstrap

Comment: @SmokeyDawson, I get some feedback that this is happening on Safari 6.2 and 7.1

Comment: @SmokeyDawson, But if it's not supported, How come that the logo image not shown?

Comment: Can you test on a safari browser 10+ ? and see if it happens just trying to eliminate the possibility

Comment: It's working on 9, But with older browsers the 2 buttons and the logo are not shown

Comment: If its working on 9 and up I wouldn't worry about it unless for some reason you 100% need to support safari 7 and under. 14.7% of users on the internet use the safari and I imagine only a small fraction of those users are using anything under 9